# Magento 1 to Magento 2 Migration Tool Issue with No Commands Defined In "Migrate" Namespace

Tags: magento-1.9, data-migration, magento2

When using the Magento Migration Tool, If I run:

```
php -f bin/magento migrate:data [-r] /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.1/config.xml
```

I get the following Response...

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                 
 There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.
```

I have googled and just found many closed issues and unable to find a solution. Has anyone found a work around for this?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help.

Please clear cache
OR
delete cache and generation folder in var directory

Answer (score 0):

> Probably the tool was installed incorrectly in magento 2 code base

[Link To Install Migration Tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html)